# Python PyQt5 progress bar doesn't update when downloading from youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube, pyqt5, youtube-dl

Progress bar does not show, neither does text, but

```py
print('hello world')
```

does which doesn't make a lot of sense. I had this working before but it seems to not work at all anymore.

I've tried using @pyqtSlot(int) with and with out that didn't work, i've tried while True: loop nothing seemed to work.

```py
    @pyqtSlot(float)
    def my_hook(self, d):
        self.progress.show()
        if d['status'] == 'finished':
            file_tuple = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(d['filename']))
            print("Done downloading {}".format(file_tuple[1]))
            self.save_history(d['filename'])

        if d['status'] == 'downloading':
            self.lblTitle.setText(d['filename'])
            self.progress.show()
            p = d['_percent_str']
            p = p.replace('%','')
            self.progress.setValue(float(p))
            self.lblState.setText(d['_total_bytes_str'] + ' at ' + d['_speed_str'] + ' ' + d['_eta_str'])
            print(d['filename'], d['_percent_str'], d['_eta_str'])
```

The progress bar should 'show' and be update to the current download..

Comment: The youtube-dl `progress_hooks` (which is fundamentally a callback) has a `dict` signature. Why are you using a `float` signature for the pyqtSlot? I cannot test right now, but what happens if you use the correct signature (or don't use a Qt slot at all)? Have you tried a simple `print(d)` at the beginning of `my_hook` to show if, at least, the callback is called to begin with?

Comment: @musicamante It works with out the pyqtSlot To be honest I don't know why I used float... it just made sense to... just printing a value in ```my_hook``` prints out what ever i need to print... Yes, it is being called.

Comment: it works randomly, with or without pyqtSlot

Comment: @JareBear use  `@pyqtSlot(dict)` and provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc `@pyqtSlot(dict)` works really well, Thank you